# Euler 4 strange probs with code in Python

Tags: python

1st Question: WHY does this warning appear about "non-ascii"? asks me to ok this: -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
2nd question: the KeyError message below the code.
THANK YOU ALL, very, very much. I value your answers and suggestions

```
    ##Largest palindrome product Problem 4
##A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the
##product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
##Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

    def is_palindrome(number):
return str(number) == str(number) [ : : -1]
    if __name__ == "__main__":
print ( " { } and {  } => {  } ".format(*max( (i, j, i*j )
                    for i in range(1000, 900, -1)
                        for j in range(1000, 900, -1)
                            if is_palindrome (i*j))))
##Traceback (most recent call last):
##  File "C:/Python27/Euler prob 4.py", line 11, in <module>
##    for i in range(1000, 900, -1)
##KeyError: ' '
```

Comment: Oof. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: noitatnedni ruoy xif esaelP. foO___ agreed! but not a prob of indentation, curious as it may seem...

Comment: Your code on your machine may be indented correctly, but the code you pasted is not.

Comment: nope. just ran it again as per gnibbler (below). i closed up the empty squiggly squirly q braces and bingo! but thanks for the exchange. i often rely on Python's auto-indent when hitting enter at end of previous line. 'curious as it may seem' all is well...

Comment: Oh, if you thought I was saying that your problem was indentation, then I apologize for being confusing. The indentation in your last four lines is not a problem because those lines are wrapped in the parentheses for your `print`. However, the rest is horribly broken. I was just pointing it out for future viewers' sake.

Comment: yes, thanks for the heads up on that. the true horribility is my incapability of formatting the initial post on this site. 8 indents, but then 4 seems to work, too. however, i got it past the automatic filter of this site... all the best!

Answer (score 1):

If you put something inside the `{}` format will try to use it as a key - even if it is a space

Comment: Hey Mr. gnibbler! 0.2 seconds flat and here it is: >>> 
 993 and 913 => 906609 ... excellent, and now, on to the next!